# CMonthCalCtrl calendar footer text (today date)

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm trying to customize the `CMonthCalCtrl` and I can't understand how can I get a footer text (the text that is used for navigation to "today" date):

[image]

I tried to use `GetCalendarGridInfo` function with `MCGIP_FOOTER` and `MCGIF_NAME` flags but it dosn't return the string:

```
    CString cText;
    MCGRIDINFO mcFooterInfo = { sizeof(MCGRIDINFO) };
    mcFooterInfo.dwPart = MCGIP_FOOTER;
    mcFooterInfo.dwFlags = MCGIF_NAME;
    mcFooterInfo.pszName = cText.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH);
    mcFooterInfo.cchName = _MAX_PATH;
    GetCalendarGridInfo(&mcFooterInfo);

    // at this point mcFooterInfo.pszName contains "9" instead of "Сегодня: 12.02.2020"
```

This returns "9" instead of a footer text.

I can't format the date by myself because I need to support current user language and I need to know how to spell the "Today:" part.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Requesting `MCGIF_NAME` for *dwPart* `MCGIP_FOOTER` [does not appear to be supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-mcgridinfo).

Comment: Also, make sure you pay attention to the return value of `GetCalendarGridInfo()`. The contents of `cText` will be undefined if FALSE is returned.

Comment: "*I need to know how to spell the "Today:" part*" - per the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/month-calendar-controls): "*The month-calendar control gets its format and **all strings** from LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT.*", so it may be possible to just query the "Today" string itself from the locale, without asking the MonthCal control at all. Except [according to this](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2012/02/02/10263136.html), the "Today" string is localized differently than how the rest of the MonthCal strings are localized. So you may be SOL on this.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to customize. Looks like NOT `Сегодня`. If it's just a date to be considered as `today`, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmonthcalctrl-class?view=vs-2019#gettoday

Comment: @VladFeinstein Well, say, for instance, I want to draw "Today: dd.mm.yyyy" using bold font or another color or whatever else. I just don't know how to get that exact string so I can `TextOut` it in a way I want.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for details on this. I'm not aware of how to query the locale string, is ther any documentation?

Comment: The API is `GetLocaleInfoEx()` but I don't think it has a way to query the translation for "today" or "tomorrow", etc - only days of the week etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to share one way of obtaining that text, even though I'm not going to use it and would not recommend anyone else to use it.

I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502375/find-localized-windows-strings/2588937#2588937) that describes the way of getting localized windows strings. I started playing with that and found that `ComCtl32.dll` contains resourse string that seems to be the one that calendar control uses. The resource that contains "Today:" string has `ID: 4432`. But this is not documented area so noone can rely on this and this may be changed from release to release.

However here's the code sample that fetches "Today:" string in different languages:

```
    GetTodayString(GetUserDefaultUILanguage()); // Сегодня:
    GetTodayString(MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_DEFAULT)); // Today:
    GetTodayString(MAKELANGID(LANG_FRENCH, SUBLANG_DEFAULT)); // Aujourd’hui :
    GetTodayString(MAKELANGID(LANG_GERMAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT)); // Heute:
    GetTodayString(MAKELANGID(LANG_SPANISH, SUBLANG_SPANISH_MODERN)); // Hoy:
    GetTodayString(MAKELANGID(LANG_UKRAINIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT)); // Сьогодні:

    CString GetTodayString(LANGID langId)
    {
        HMODULE hComCtl32 = LoadLibrary(_T("comctl32.dll"));
        if (!hComCtl32)
            return _T("");

        UINT nResourceId = 4432; // I don't think that anyone should rely on this
        CString cResourceStr = FindStringResourceEx(hComCtl32, nResourceId, langId);

        FreeLibrary(hComCtl32);

        int delimiterIdx = cResourceStr.Find(_T('\x6'));
        CString cTodayStr = cResourceStr.Left(delimiterIdx);

        return cTodayStr;
    }

    CString FindStringResourceEx(HINSTANCE hinst, UINT uId, UINT langId)
    {
        // Convert the string ID into a bundle number
        LPCWSTR pwsz = NULL;
        HRSRC hrsrc = FindResourceEx(hinst, RT_STRING,
            MAKEINTRESOURCE(uId / 16 + 1),
            langId);
        if (hrsrc) {
            HGLOBAL hglob = LoadResource(hinst, hrsrc);
            if (hglob) {
                pwsz = reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>
                    (LockResource(hglob));
                if (pwsz) {
                    // okay now walk the string table
                    for (int i = 0; i < (uId & 15); i++) {
                        pwsz += 1 + (UINT)*pwsz;
                    }

                    pwsz += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return CString(pwsz);
    }
```

As I said, I'm not going to use this approach and probably I will simply omit the "Today:" text and display only formatted today date in the footer.